# can not pass id with button in php

Tags: php

Here is my html code i want to pass order_id with button but i can not pass value with 
button on next page its give same value on next page i do not know wer is my mistake. i am also pass that button value with hidden variable. stil give me same result.

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center"> 
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Order No</th>
                  <th>Party Name</th>
                  <th>Karigar Name</th>
                  <th>Order Date</th>
                  <th>Delivery Date</th>
                  <th>Next Date</th>
                  <th>New Date</th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
               <tfoot>
                 <tr>
                  <th>Order No</th>
                  <th>Party Name</th>
                  <th>Karigar Name</th>
                  <th>Order Date</th>
                  <th>Delivery Date</th>
                  <th>Next Date</th>
                  <th>New Date</th>
                  <th></th>

                </tr>
               </tfoot>
              <tbody>
                  {section name="sec" loop=$categoryArray}
                  <tr>
                    <td>{$categoryArray[sec].order_no}</td>
                    <td>{$categoryArray[sec].buyer}</td>
                    <td>{$categoryArray[sec].seller}</td>
                    <td>{$categoryArray[sec].order_dt}</td>
                    <td>{$categoryArray[sec].del_dt}</td>
                    <td>{$categoryArray[sec].del_dt}</td>
                    <td>
                     {html_select_date prefix="o_dt" start_year="-1" end_year="+0" field_order="DMY" day_value_format="%02d"}
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:50px;">
                      <input style="width:50px;" type="hidden" name="order_id">
                      <input type="submit" name="action" class="btn" value="Submit">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  {/section}

              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: You need a form unless you want to gather the data and send via AJAX.

Comment: is it not possible without ajax..

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your form in `<form>` tag:

```
<form action="...">
  <input style="width:50px;" type="hidden" name="order_id">
  <input type="submit" name="action" class="btn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Otherwise each `order_id` input will override before one.

Comment: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /hg/... on this server.